# PDF Direct printing using Python - socket timeout error

Tags: python, sockets, printing, tcp

I am trying to create a small python script that sends a pdf to a network printer directly on the tcp 9100 port and throws an error when the printer is offline.
To do so I was thinking of using the socket timeout but when I use this the printer prints the following:

```
Error Name:           /syntaxerror
Offending Command:    (!)
Operand Stack:
```

Below you can find my code. without the settimeout this is working and the printer is printing the pdf, when I add this line the printer is printing a paper with the error above.

```
import socket
import sys

host = "1.1.1.1"
port = 9100

try:
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.settimeout(10.0) 
    f = open ("my.pdf", "rb")
    l = f.read()
    s.send(l)
    f.close()
    s.close()
except Exception as inst: 
    print("Pdf not printed")
```

How can I detect that my printer is offline?

Comment: One thing to notice is that `s.send(l)` may not send all of `l`, but only the first part. Use `s.sendall(l)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about sharing the exact PostScript error message, as printed, rather than a link to a probably unrelated problem ?

It would also be useful to capture the PostScript being sent with, and without, the socket timeout, and compare the two programs.

I'd have to guess that the problem is the printer doesn't respond within the stated timeout (presumably its busy processing the input so far), which causes the socket to time out and terminate. If the whole file hasn't been transferred to the printer then it won't be able to print it (you can't parse a partial PDF file) and will, not unreasonably, throw an error.

Have you tried a simpler test file, or a longer timeout ?

Have you tried to see if your printer will respond to a ping (assuming python supports ping)? If so that would be a reasonably quick way to determine whether its offline.

This doesn't really seem to be a PostScript question though......

Comment: I updated my question and removed the postscript tag. I tried with a longer timeout but this is generating the same error. I haven't tried other files then pdf. I will try with pinging the printer, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, all I can really say from that is that the interpreter received an '!' character when it wasn't expecting one. Its odd that it would even throw a PostScript error while processing a PDF file (PDF is not PostScript), but possibly the printer does an internal conversion from PDF to PostScript.

Comment: Indeed because I'm sending directly the pdf to the printer without driver the printer does the conversion to postscript. I'm using a Kyocera printer for this with their KPDL-emulator on.